# Yup: how to compare one field with other? Ref neither parent.field not working

Tags: reactjs, yup

This is the yup schema:

```
 let schema = yup.object().shape({
        password: yup.string().required('Enter password'),
        confirm: yup.string().required('Re-enter password')
                    .test('passwords-match', 'Password and confirmation do not match', function(value){
                        const t = yup.ref('password'); // some bulky object
                        const t1 = t.getValue(); // undefined too
                        const t2 = this.parent.password; // undefined too
                        const a = this.resolve(t)      // undefined even after entering value
                        return a === value
                    })
```

For some reason, comparison with another field is not working.
What am I missing?

Some idea just came to me. Maybe something is wrong with this validator I'm using from here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-97lr5s?file=index.js

The full code from there:

```
import * as yup from 'yup';

let schema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required(),
  age: yup
    .number()
    .required()
    .typeError('Number only.')
    .positive()
    .integer()
    .round(),
  a: yup
    .number()
    .required()
    .typeError('Number only.')
    .positive()
    .integer()
    .round().test('', 'asdf', function(v){ 
      console.log(this.parent.name) // undefined
      return v == this.parent.age}), // okay?
});

const yupSync = {
  async validator({ field }, value) {
    await schema.validateSyncAt(field, { [field]: value });
  },
};

const DynamicRule = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  return (
    <Form form={form} name="form1">
      <Form.Item name="name" label="Name" rules={[yupSync]}>
        <Input placeholder="Please input your name" />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item name="age" label="Age" rules={[yupSync]}>
        <Input placeholder="Please input age" />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item name="a" label="Age" rules={[yupSync]}>
        <Input placeholder="Please input a" />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can compare two fields in Yup. You're almost there but just need some additional info in order to compare two fields.

**Working example:**

```
    Yup.object().shape({
    password: Yup.string().min(8).required("Password is required"),
    confirmPassword: Yup.string()
      .when("password", { // this should match with input field name
        is: (val) => (val && val.length > 0 ? true : false),
        then: Yup.string().oneOf(
          [Yup.ref("password")],
          "Both Password need to be same"
        ),
      })
      .required("Confirm Password is required"),
  }),
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not working.